# ParseFile error when generating Swagger docs

Tags: go, swagger

I'm using Swagger to generate docs with Golang.

I have generated successfully for a few times. However, the last time I ran `swag init` (at root folder), it ran into this problem:

```
swag init
2019/07/17 11:10:43 Generate swagger docs....
2019/07/17 11:10:43 Generate general API Info, search dir:./
2019/07/17 11:10:48 ParseFile error:pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20190712213246-8b927904ee0d/cmd/fiximports/testdata/src/old.com/bad/bad.go:2:43: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
```

What is this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue; it resolved after installing previous version of swag.

The command to install that specific version is:

`go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@v1.4.1`